# Progressbar not working ngx-bootstrap

Tags: html, angular, progress-bar, ngx-bootstrap

I found following description for `value` attribute of progress-bar.
Current value of progress-bar, could be a number or array of objects like `{"value":15,"type":"info","label":"15 %"}`

While using it I passed the value as:

```html
<progressbar max="100" [value]="[{'value':15,'type':'success','label':'15 %'}, {'value':15,'type':'danger','label':'15 %'}]" [striped]="true" [animate]="true"><i></i></progressbar>
```

But, it is not giving me a progress-bar with success and danger together. Am I doing something wrong please guide?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're only supposed to give one value at a time for one type of progress-bar to be shown.

Try this:

```
<progressbar max="100" [value]="progressValue" [striped]="true" [animate]="true"><i></i></progressbar>
```

Then on the component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.progressValue = {'value':15,'type':'success','label':'15 %'};
    setTimeout(() => this.progressValue = {'value':15,'type':'danger','label':'15 %'}, 3000);
```

You're not changing the value and type with `setTimeout`, rather depending on other actions.

Comment: Hi Zlatko I am trying to achieve multiple bars functionality of bootstrap using ngx-bootstrap but here I can put only one object. Is it possible to achieve in ngx

Comment: Here I want to show two different types of progress in single progressbar(success and danger together)

Answer (score 0):

Thank's everyone for response.
I was trying to show multiple progress in same progressbar. So when I tried to implement using ngx-bootstrap I was facing the above issue. 
Same thing I am able to do using normal bootstrap and some angular 5 things.

```html
<div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar bg-success progress-bar-animated progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" [style.width.%]="progress.correctPer" [attr.aria-valuenow]="progress.correctPer" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">{{(progress.correctPer ? (progress.correctPer + '%'):'')}}</div>
            <div class="progress-bar bg-danger progress-bar-animated progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" [style.width.%]="progress.wrongPer" [attr.aria-valuenow]="progress.wrongPer" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">{{(progress.wrongPer ? (progress.wrongPer+'%'):'')}}</div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of ngx-bootstrap@2.0.2 has this issue. This will be fixed in next releases or you can use custom css fix right now:

```
progressbar.progress {
    display: flex;
}
```